# How to get and set string Resource values in android

Tags: android, string, android-resources

I've declare a `String`:

```
<string name="Please">Please Select</string>
```

in the `res/values/Strings.xml`. Now I want to access this `String` value but what I can get can go till id not value like:

```
 int i = findViewById(R.string.Please);
```

But what I want is just the value of the string `Please`.

Thanks for all of your answer but my problem is a little bigger

What I wanted to do is just to display date with app_name

from all your answers i can get the app_name String 
but whether I can set 
This app_name with current date

```
<string name="app_name">My app</string>
```

and also I'm to set my in this way

```
My app(in Left alignment)             Date (in right aligment)
```

and also on start of first activity i want to set app_name and not on every activity;

I think it may work let me try

```
setResource().setString(R.string.Please);
```

but no setResource() method sorry.

Comment: you can accept one of answer below if it helped you

Comment: let me get answer what i want i'll do it's not an issue

Comment: `can go till id not value like`  what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cant set a string, its static, and cant be changed at run-time, what you want to do is something like this

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String date = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        setTitle(date);
```

Your trying to set the title as the date right?

To have two titles it is a bit harder, first you need a layout, call this custom_title_1

This is the xml code for that layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/left_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/custom_title_left" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/right_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/custom_title_right" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your code before you call the UI you need to call this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

then set you content view

then call this which will set the title:

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_1);
```

Now you can find the two textViews and set the text:

```
TextView leftText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.left_text);
TextView rightText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right_text);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String date = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String app_name = getString(R.string.app_name);
leftText.setText(app_name);
rightText.setText(date);
```

Comment: you got wrong i did like this but what i actually wanted to set the strings stored in strings.xml under res/strings/
there you have found string app_name what i wanted to set this from my code
don't hurry 
read whole question

Comment: Did you see the rest of it? I dont think I got anything wrong?

Comment: You cant change strings in the strings.xml file, the best you can do is this, every time the application is run it will take half a ms to load this, also you get the alignment, can you explain more in a comment here if you wanted something different?  This is what I understood is what you want.

Comment: Btw I was editing it because I was reading through what I already had, saving it as I went along

Comment: you must read thisline
and also on start of first activity i want to set app_name and not on every activity;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9947/discussion-between-photon-and-smartlemon)

Answer (score 12):

Try like this

```
String temp = getResources().getString(R.string.Please);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
String value = getResources().getString(R.string.Please);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 String str = getResources().getString(R.string.Please);
```

Answer (score 1):

String resources are not views. To use a string resource you would do

```
@string/Please
```